# How to config a Kafka producer to stop retrying to connect to broker if isn't available

Tags: java, kotlin, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

How to config a Kafka producer to stop retrying to connect to broker if isn't available?
I added the retries configuration, but it doesn't work, it still keep retrying indefinitely...
I want to skip this part if "Broker may not be available"
How to fix it?

There is my Kafka Producer config:

```
    @Bean
    fun notificationKafkaProducerFactory(): ProducerFactory<String, Email> {
        val config = mutableMapOf<String, Any>()
        config[ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG] = "localhost:9092"
        config[ProducerConfig.MAX_IN_FLIGHT_REQUESTS_PER_CONNECTION] = "3"
        config[ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG] = "3"
        config[ProducerConfig.RETRY_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG] = "500"
        config[ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = JsonSerializerWithJTM::class.java
        config[ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG] = JsonSerializerWithJTM::class.java

        return DefaultKafkaProducerFactory(config)
    }

    @Bean
    fun notificationKafkaTemplate(): KafkaTemplate<String, Email> {
        return KafkaTemplate(notificationKafkaProducerFactory())
    }
```

Above how does it look when trying sending a message:

```
2023-03-19 14:17:23.298  INFO 70901 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.k.clients.producer.ProducerConfig    : ProducerConfig values: 
        acks = -1
    batch.size = 16384
    bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
    buffer.memory = 33554432
    client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
    client.id = producer-1
    compression.type = none
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    delivery.timeout.ms = 120000
    enable.idempotence = true
    interceptor.classes = []
    key.serializer = class com.fomichev.september.service.notification.email.templates.JsonSerializerWithJTM
    linger.ms = 0
    max.block.ms = 60000
    max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 3
    max.request.size = 1048576
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metadata.max.idle.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retries = 3
    retry.backoff.ms = 500
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.connect.timeout.ms = null
    sasl.login.read.timeout.ms = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.login.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
    sasl.login.retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    sasl.oauthbearer.clock.skew.seconds = 30
    sasl.oauthbearer.expected.audience = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.expected.issuer = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.refresh.ms = 3600000
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.url = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.scope.claim.name = scope
    sasl.oauthbearer.sub.claim.name = sub
    sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url = null
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    security.providers = null
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.engine.factory.class = null
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
    ssl.keystore.key = null
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.certificates = null
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
    transactional.id = null
    value.serializer = class com.fomichev.september.service.notification.email.templates.JsonSerializerWithJTM

...

2023-03-19 14:17:23.639  INFO 70901 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer     : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Instantiated an idempotent producer.
2023-03-19 14:17:23.738  INFO 70901 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 3.1.1
2023-03-19 14:17:23.738  INFO 70901 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: 97671528ba54a138
2023-03-19 14:17:23.738  INFO 70901 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1679221043736
2023-03-19 14:17:23.894  INFO 70901 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-03-19 14:17:23.895  WARN 70901 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-03-19 14:17:23.895  WARN 70901 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2023-03-19 14:17:24.403  INFO 70901 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-03-19 14:17:24.404  WARN 70901 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-03-19 14:17:24.404  WARN 70901 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
```

Comment: The kafka-clients provides no API to check the broker availability; you can reduce `max.block.ms` to time out faster.